# storage_usage View in Account_usage Schema showing data for all warehouse/projects?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, usage-tracking

Does the storage_usage View in Account_usage Schema reflect data for all warehouse/projects within the company?
Is there a way to filter  data just for a team or project like we have warehouse name field in WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY  view?

If data in this view(storage_usage) is project specific then how does this view get loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is answering your question:

1. STORAGE_USAGE contains data across all database, all schemas, all stages and all tables across your account.
2. Data is historized for 1 year.
3. Latency is about 2 hours.
4. The view is showing the average daily data storage usage per type (STORAGE, FAILSAFE, STAGE)

Doc: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/storage_usage.html

Maybe the following 2 views are helping you in additon:

1. DATABASE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY is helping you more. Here you can see the used average storage per database and filter accordingly - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/database_storage_usage_history.html
2. TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS is containing storage information per table - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/table_storage_metrics.html